# TypeError: yaml.Schema.create is not a function

Tags: yaml

In my typescript/node application, I am using `js-yaml` version 4.1.0 (installed through yarn), and in my code I have the following:

```
import * as yaml from 'js-yaml';

const CF_SCHEMA = yaml.Schema.create([
  new yaml.Type('!Ref', {
    kind: 'scalar',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { Ref: data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Equals', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Equals': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Not', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Not': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Sub', {
    kind: 'scalar',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Sub': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!If', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::If': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Join', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Join': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Select', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Select': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!FindInMap', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::FindInMap': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!GetAtt', {
    kind: 'sequence',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::GetAtt': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!GetAZs', {
    kind: 'scalar',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::GetAZs': data };
    },
  }),
  new yaml.Type('!Base64', {
    kind: 'mapping',
    construct: function (data) {
      return { 'Fn::Base64': data };
    },
  }),
]);
```

However, when I run this code I get the error:

```
const CF_SCHEMA = yaml.Schema.create([
                              ^
TypeError: yaml.Schema.create is not a function
```

The code I used was written in accordance with https://gist.github.com/olegch/37212ba350cabca921fd3109df2d1981 - would anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

There was a change made with version 4.0.0 of js-yaml.

> `yaml.Schema.create(schema, tags)` is removed, use `schema.extend(tags)` instead

- [js-yaml CHANGELOG.md 4.0.0](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400---2021-01-03)

Now instead of doing `yaml.Schema.create` you pick an existing schema and extend it, so you propably want `yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend([...])`

Comment: yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend([...]) worked for me   -thanks!!